# What is JSON and ymal models in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am new to TensorFlow. I could not understand the doc of "JSON" and "ymal". What do these modules actually do? Here is the link to them:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are common file formats, not too different from .txt or .csv files.

They store data that will be read and written to by TensorFlow in your case. When you train a model you will be able to save it in a JSON or YAML format. These formats are generally pretty human-readable.

The functions you are referring to can load a saved model configuration from a JSON or YAML file.